# Wrapping HTML code around excel list of items

Tags: html, excel, append

Basically, I have an excel list of a bunch of city names, and need to prepend:

```
<option value="
```

and append

```
">
```

So the end result is a list of something like:

```
<option value="Los Angeles">
```

and I'm sadly struggling with an efficient way to do so.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an XLS file? It might be easier to save it out as a CSV - they are much easier to parse.

Comment: I wasn't really using a XLS file, I just had dropped the list into Excel (to clean it up) as I had pulled it from a Wikipedia article.  I just wanted to clean it up and then get it wrapped with code and drop it into a webpage, which worked with Joshua's answer.

Comment: Sorry - the way it was worded and that it was tagged as PHP related earlier looked like you wanted to read from a XLS file and parse it using PHP. Glad it was resolved for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a formula to do this.  Assuming your city name is in cell `B2` just place this formula in the cell you want the appended and prepended text to be.

```
="<option value="""&B1&""">"
```

The character escaping can be a bit tricky!

Comment: Sigh, I was escaping the characters incorrectly in excel (using a \ like a moron).  Thanks, this did the trick.